# How to fix dates discrepancy between MS SQL Server 2008R2/2012 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2008, date, sql-server-2012

We store dates in the DB as a diff between the date and '1-Jan-1970' in minutes.

Here're the results from the same machine:

```
--TSQL (MS Sql Server 2008R2)
SELECT DATEADD(minute, 22572765, '1-Jan-1970'); -- gets 1-Dec-2012 12:45:00.000

//JS (Chrome) - assume minDate = 1-Jan-1970
new Date(minDate.getTime() + (22572765 * 60 * 1000)) -- gets me 1-Jan-2013 12:45:00
```

What's the best way to solve the discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like your `minDate` is wrong, because this:

```
new Date((new Date(1970, 0, 1)).getTime() + (22572765 * 60 * 1000))
```

...gives me 1-Dec-2012 12:45:00.000 GMT.

In JavaScript, the `month` value is zero-based, so if you're constructing `minDate` with `new Date(1970, 1, 1)`, that's why you're a month out.

---

Also note that unless you use the `UTC` variants of things (`getUTCYear`, etc.), JavaScript dates will give you the *local* timezone version of the date on output (your way of *constructing* the date is correct other than `minDate`, it's just on output you need to be careful).

Comment: you're a some legend.

Comment: are there any cases when the parity is broken though (leap years, DST etc.) or everything's been looked after?

Comment: @user1514042: DST doesn't come into it with since-the-Epoch values. Leap years are handled. JavaScript uses an [extrapolated Gregorian calendar](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.3). Days are always exactly 86,400,000ms long (no leap seconds).